# Como imprimir comandos de compilação e linkagem no CMake?

Tags: compilação, makefile, cmake

Tenho um projeto que usa o **CMake** e gostaria de imprimir os comandos de compilação gerados por ele. Como fazer isso?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Se você quer que os comandos de compilação *sempre* sejam impressos, coloque a seguinte linha no `CMakeLists.txt`:

```
SET(CMAKE_VERBOSE_MAKEFILE ON)
```

Se você quer imprimir os comandos de compilação apenas algumas vezes, após rodar o CMake, rode o `make` da seguinte maneira:

```
make VERBOSE=1
```

Answer (score 0):

Não sei se entendi bem a pergunta, mas se voce estiver querendo imprimir uma mensagem tipo "Gerando Objetos" ou "linkando bibliotecas" basta colocar assim depois de cada regra

```
all: dependencia1 dependencia2 ....
    @echo "Gerando executavel"
```

e ele vai imprimir essa string quando estiver realizando essa regra.